# Elasticsearch Suggest API -Can't search numbers

Tags: autocomplete, elasticsearch, autosuggest

I'm using the Suggest API to create an autocomplete for restaurant names, but I've run into a small problem. Some restaurant names start with numbers, for example:

```
68 - 86 Bar & Restaurant
```

I want to be able to type `68` and get the restaurant back. I've tried using the whitespace analyzer, but it doesn't fix my issue.

Here is the analyze output for the restaurant name:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "68",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "86",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "bar",
      "start_offset": 8,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "restaurant",
      "start_offset": 14,
      "end_offset": 24,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Here are the commands to reproduce my issue:

```
PUT restaurants
{ }

PUT restaurants/restaurant/_mapping
{
    "location": {
        "index_analyzer": "whitespace",
        "search_analyzer": "whitespace", 
        "properties": {
            "name_suggest": {
                "type": "completion",
                "payloads": true
            }
        }
    }
}

POST restaurants/restaurant/1
{
    "name_suggest": {
        "input": [
            "68 - 86 Bar & Restaurant"
        ],
        "output": "68 - 86 Bar & Restaurant",
        "payload": { 
            "id": 1067
        }
    }
}

POST restaurants/_suggest
{
    "suggestions": {
        "text": "68 - 86",
        "completion": {
            "field": "name_suggest"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get any results from _suggest. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

I've solved it, simple really, but maybe a bug?

Instead of:

```
PUT restaurants/restaurant/_mapping
{
    "location": {
        "index_analyzer": "whitespace",
        "search_analyzer": "whitespace", 
        "properties": {
            "name_suggest": {
                "type": "completion",
                "payloads": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I now have:

```
PUT restaurants/restaurant/_mapping
{
    "location": {
        "properties": {
            "name_suggest": {
                "type": "completion",
                "index_analyzer": "whitespace",
                "search_analyzer": "whitespace",
                "payloads": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just came across this problem myself, seems Simple Analyzer doesn't work for numbers... thanks for sharing!

Comment: Nice one, had the same problem

Comment: what does `"index_analyzer": "whitespace"` mean?